# Update Authority of Candy Machine

Tags: solana, metaplex, candy-machine

I transfer authority of Candy Machine to a new wallet address using this command line

```
ts-node ~/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts update_candy_machine \
-e devnet \
-k ~/.config/solana/devnet.json \
-cp config.json \
-c temp \
--new-authority BwoAzDMxFVrG7tSdcBzy1H4yUcVX2FaDUFkCFVWMBbAL
```

But after transfer authority the mint stopped

> Program logged: "Instruction: SetCollectionDuringMint"
> Program invoked: Token Metadata Program
> Program logged: "Instruction: Set and Verify Collection"
> Program logged: "Update Authority given does not match"
> Program consumed: 7483 of 1040268 compute units
> Program returned error: "custom program error: 0x7"
> Program consumed: 34700 of 1067485 compute units
> Program returned error: "custom program error: 0x7"

I try to get back authority and the mint work again

https://explorer.solana.com/address/7ARq1Nxca8hfvzAnBsM7kq2tHWtHT6uE4teAVJPp3LtJ?cluster=devnet

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because in order to set the collection during mint, the CandyMachine Authority and the collection NFT authority must match. When you create a Candy Machine all the NFTs will use as authority the pubkey of the wallet who create the CandyMachine, when you create the collection (using the webpage or just using the default one that is created during upload) the authority of this collection is the same pubkey that you used to create the Candy Machine.

So when you update the authority of the Candy Machine, the newly minted NFTs from this Candy Machine will have this new authority pubkey, but will still use the same collection that has the old authority pubkey, so when you try to set the collection to this new NFT it will find that NFT authority and collection authority does not match and will throw the error.

How to fix? you can just update the authority of the collection NFT (and all the old NFTs too) [using metaboss](https://metaboss.rs/set.html#set-update-authority-all), in order that ur collection authority match the new authority on the CandyMachine